# Number of ways to deal 52 cards so that any of 4 players gets dealt all cards of same suit

Tags: combinatorics

We have an ordinary deck of cards and we deal $13$ cards to each player. Count the number of deals possible such that at least one of the $4$ players would have $13$ cards of the same suit.

The problem appeared much simpler at first glance, however I'm having trouble handling double counting cases. Simply trying to count cases wasn't fruitful, so I decided to try getting the probability of such a deal happening and then multiplying by the number of all possible deals.

A single player may get a single suit deal with a probability of $P = 4/{52 \choose 13}$, however this  also includes cases where other players get dealt a single suit hand. This means the total probability of there being at least 1 single suit hand cannot simply be $4P$.

I have also thought about each player's probability being $P_n = P *(probability\;of\;previous\;players\;not\;being\;dealt\;suits)$, where $n$ is the number of the player, $n\in \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$. For example, $P_1 = P, \;P_2 = P * (1-P_1)$. This, however, I'm not sure is correct and I'm having trouble proving/disproving it. If it was correct, though, simply adding these probabilities would suffice.

Any help or other methods would be super helpful.

Comment: Are you familiar with the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)?

Comment: Not formally, though I believe I've used it without realizing it.

Comment: Do you know how many hands there are in which a player has all the cards of a given suit?